# How to know whether WinForms can render certain menu fonts?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, fonts

I have a WinForms application written in Visual C++/CLR. I have a "Languages" menu which drops down to show the available languages and which one is currently selected. The languages are written in their native form, e.g. instead of "German" it shows "Deutsch".

[image: Mine]

Some of these languages are written in different alphabets/fonts, such as Russian and Traditional Chinese. On my machine, they render fine, but some users have reported to me that certain languages render as gibberish/garbage on their machines, as you can see here:

[image: Theirs]

Is there a way to correct this, or at least detect it? Currently I load these language names from folder names (a language is supported and thus listed if a folder exists with certain data files inside it). Ideally I can do something to make it "just work" but I could live with detecting a missing font and falling back to a Romanized/English version if I have to.

Comment: Going to need more details to help... are you using default system fonts? or shipping custom fonts with your deployment? If you deploy your own fonts you can use the private font collection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-a-private-font-collection

Comment: I am not shipping any fonts currently. So I guess it just uses system fonts, which apparently can be unavailable for some people... is there a way to easily make a private font available to all controls?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, our controls are custom styled so they live in common library where we just use a singleton for the font collection. You can work with the system fonts, there's just never a guarantee what a particular system might have installed but perhaps you can find some logic that works for you? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-enumerate-installed-fonts . You could create a list of common CJK font families Windows uses and search for family or fallback to alternative?